# How to view or get the service connection id in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to view or get the service connection ids for the service connections that I create in Azure DevOps?

[image: Service Connections in Azure DevOps]

I need them in yaml pipelines that I create. For example, dockerRegistryServiceConnection that you see in the following is used in the docker@02 task for setting containerRegistry, if you see below.

```
variables:
- name: vmImageName
  value: ubuntu-latest

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
- name: dockerRegistryServiceConnection
  value: 'd072f8f7-fag1-asdf-467e-7fd5jfr5gjh6'  # This is not a true id
- name: imageRepository
  value: 'globoticket.services.discount'
- name: containerRegistry
  value: 'reacrtrialsregistry.azurecr.io'
- name: dockerfileFolderPath
  value: 'src/Services/GloboTicket.Services.Discount'
- name: tag
  value: '$(Build.BuildId)'


name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)

stages:

  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: buildWebApp
        displayName: Build Release pipeline for Discount Service on Master branch
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:

        - checkout: self

        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Build the image 
          inputs:
            command: build
            repository: $(imageRepository)
            dockerfile: $(dockerfileFolderPath)/Dockerfile
            buildContext: .
            tags: |
              $(tag)  
        
        - script: |
            sudo docker tag $(imageRepository):$(tag) $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
          displayName: 'Tag container image before push'

        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Push an tagged image to container registry
          inputs:
            command: push
            repository: $(imageRepository)
            dockerfile: $(dockerfileFolderPath)/Dockerfile
            buildContext: . 
            containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
            tags: |
              $(tag)      

  - stage: DeployToDev
    displayName: Deploy to Dev Env
    jobs:
      - deployment:
      
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        environment: Dev
        strategy: 
         runOnce:
           deploy:
             steps:
              - script: |
                    echo Any deploy stage starts here.
                displayName: 'Command Line Script to write out some messages'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input for the `containerRegistry` input for the docker task is the *name* of the service connection, not the id, [according to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs):

> Container registry    (Optional):  Name of the Docker registry service
> connection

If you still need the ID, you can click the service connection in the list under `Project Settings -> Service Connections` and fetch the service connection ID from the resourceId parameter in the url:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All Azure Tasks I know are using the **service connection name**, not the Id. The same is true for the Docker@2 Task:

[image]

[Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#task-inputs)